# Pretty splitting of lines?

Tags: php, clean-code

```
<?php
        if (in_array(exec("pboxsvc pboxlib.bin DeterminarTipoSpool' $idJob"),
                     ['IPP','PSFORM','PBSSFORM','PDF'])):
    ?>
```

How would you refactor that line to be "eye-candy" and actually note what is going on easily?

I often come to the need of splitting lines in conditionals having functions, or arrays, etc, is there any online compilation?

Comment: Seems intuitive to me. Maybe assign the exec results to a variable first with a meaningful name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of competing styles for formatting function arguments. All of them make sense, but have differences regarding vertical and horizontal space usage, commentability, and how clearly diffs will point out the change.

The styles can first be divided by where they place the first function argument: On the same line or on the second line:

```
// same line
foo(bar,
    baz)

// separate line
foo(
    bar,
    baz
)
```

Placing the argument on the same line is more compact, but placing everything on a line of its own leads to better diffs: If we see that the line `foo(bar,` was changed, we do not immediately know whether the function or the argument were changed.

The second choice is how to align arguments on the consecutive lines. We can either use a fixed indent, or align them with the parentheses of the function call:

```
// fixed indent
foobar(
    baz,
    qux
)

// align with parens
foobar(baz,
       qux)
```

Using a fixed indent keeps the total indentation of the arguments smaller, leaving more horizontal space to be used. You could e.g. use this space for a line comment to explain what each argument means. Aligning the arguments at the opening parenthesis looks better, especially when you do not place the first argument on a line of its own. The remaining line for each argument is rather short, which also happens to discourage deep nesting. Whether or not that's a good thing is another debate.

However you decide to place your arguments, it is important that they are vertically aligned. So this style makes little sense:

```
foobar(baz,
    qux)
```

Then, we can choose where to place the closing parenthesis. We can either put it immediately after the last argument (which is nice and compact), or put it on a line of its own, where we can align it with the function name, the opening parenthesis, or somewhere in between.

```
// same line
foobar(baz,
       qux)

// align with function name
foobar(
  baz,
  qux,
)

// align with opening paren
foobar(
       baz,
       qux,
      )

// somewhere in between
foobar
  (
    baz,
    qux
  )
```

Using a line of its own has the advantage that adding a line for another argument only marks that line as changed in a diff; otherwise the previous line would also be changed because you have to remove the parenthesis. If you place the closing parenthesis on a line of its own and your language supports this (PHP does), then you should also put a comma after the last argument as well, for this same reason.

If you align the closing paren with the function name, this creates a strong visual relation between the function and the closing paren, but aligning it with the opening paren clearly demarks the block of arguments. The exact same arguments as for bracing style apply here, where some ecosystems favour “egyptian brackets”, while others prefer to put each brace on a line of its own.

So, there's a good argument for almost any style. The important part is to make a well-informed choice and stick to it. I prefer styles that enhance diffability and allow deep nesting:

```
foobar(
  baz,
  qux,
)
```

Comment: When I do this kind of stuff (sql/what ever) I like to put le commat before the argurment so this way I don't need any extra commat but I still have only 1 line diff when add param/what ever